# How to write a bash script to trigger next command if and only if the previous command's process is completed

Tags: linux, bash

I have a command like this which will trigger a process

```
./extract.sh 1553212800 1554854400 &
```

This will give a process id for example `1234`

and I want to run next command only if `1234` is completed

```
./extract.sh 1554854400 1556668800 &
```

There are multiple commands like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems unnecessary to put it in the background if you want to wait for it to complete anyway but:

```
./extract.sh 1553212800 1554854400 & 
pid=$!
if wait "$pid"; then
    ./extract.sh 1554854400 1556668800 & 
fi
```

The `wait` builtin exits with:

> Returns the status of the last ID; fails if ID is invalid or an invalid option is given.

Comment: Hi Jesse! I WANT TO keep in the background because I am gonna log out of the computer 

I have multiple commands like this 
do u want me to keep multiple if's ?

Comment: @johndoe Run the jobs in a detached `screen` or `tmux` session? In that case you _don't_ need to run them as background tasks. It would also prevent the shell from terminating them when you log out (if you properly detach from the session).  You should add this context to the question, because Jesse's answer answers the question as it is currently posed (as does mine).

Answer (score 1):

You would either just remove the `&` at the end of each command, which would make the shell run the commands *not* as background tasks, or, if you really need to run them as background tasks (because you're also doing other things in parallel), you would need to save the process' PID in a variable and then `wait` for it to finish:

```
./extract.sh 1553212800 1554854400 & pid="$!"

# other things

wait "$pid"

./extract.sh 1554854400 1556668800 &  & pid="$!"

# other things (again)

wait "$pid"

# etc.
```

---

Personally, if I had a long list of these sorts of commands, I would put them all in a single script like

```
#!/bin/sh

./extract.sh 1553212800 1554854400
./extract.sh 1554854400 1556668800
```

(note, no background jobs)

Then I would probably start the script with `nohup`:

```
nohup ./script.sh &
```

This would allow me to log out and then log back in to see whether the script process was still running (by checking using `ps`).

Or, I would simply start a `tmux` session, then start the script as ordinary (no `nohup`), and press <kbd>Ctrl+B</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> to detach from it.  Later, I could get back to the same shell session with `tmux attach`.  See the `tmux` manual.

Comment: Cool what if I will log out will the script keep running? 
Sorry to trouble you, I am still learning what is what !
you are doing a big help to me!

Comment: @johndoe See update. But really, you should add all relevant information to the question rather than asking followup questions in comments.

Comment: I am sorry I think that helps a lot !! 
As I said i am still learning so ......... I will for sure keep in mind for next time `nohup` helps !! I will read about `tmux` ........thank you very much!

Comment: This answer is better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

While this may not directly answer the question as stated, I thought I would bring up this solution, especially since it looks like OP hasn't settled on pipeline yet.

In many Posix shell, it is possible to chain multiple commands together via the `&&` symbol. Basically, it means run the first command, then after the first command runs to completion without error, run the following commands after the `&&`. For example:

```
./extract.sh 1553212800 1554854400 && ./extract.sh 1554854400 1556668800 &
```

This will, however, run everything as a single large background process. Also, you run the risk of never running the commands that follow a command that throws an error. So in a scenario like this one:

```
./valid_run.sh && ./throws_error.sh && ./second_valid_run.sh
```

If `valid_run.sh` runs properly and `throws_error.sh` does not, the `second_valid_run.sh` will not run.

Alternatively, a cleaner approach to this would be to keep all your commands in a wrapper BASH script then run that script:

wrapper.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
./extract.sh 1553212800 1554854400
./extract.sh 1554854400 1556668800
```

command line:

```
$ ./wrapper.sh &
```

I think this may be the best way to organize your commands.